# typescript interface with different number of types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a custom hook like this, I want to make request parameter optional and response required:

```
function useRequest<T, S = any>(api: (input?: S) => Promise<T>) {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<T | null>(null);

  const fetchData = useCallback(
    (input?: S) => {
      api(input)
        .then((data) => {
          setResponse(data as T);
        })
    },
    [api],
  );
  return { response, fetchData };
}
```

Basically I want to call `useRequest` like this:

```
function A()
{
  //return a promise
}
function B(p1: boolean) {
  //return a promise
}

useRequest<ResponseA>(A)
useRequest<ResponseB, boolean>(B)
```

but I cannot use second one since the `boolean` is not compatible with `boolean | undefined`.

Comment: changing `function B(p1: boolean)` to `function B(p1?: boolean)` also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to limit yourself to just one parameter, using [tuples in rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) you can capture the type of the parameters and spread them back out to a new function. The effect of this is that the arity of the function is preserved:

```
import { useState, useCallback} from 'react'

function useRequest<T, P extends any[]>(api: (...params: P) => Promise<T>) {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<T | null>(null);

  const fetchData = useCallback(
    (...params: P) => {
      api(...params)
        .then((data) => {
          setResponse(data as T);
        })
    },
    [api],
  );
  return { response, fetchData };
}


type ResponseA = { a: string }
type ResponseB = { b: string }
declare function A(): Promise<ResponseA>;
declare function B(p1: boolean): Promise<ResponseB>;

useRequest(A)
useRequest(B)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=25&ssc=14&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAwjgDbkBGOAxgNYC+cAZlBCHAORTp0xcAsACgRLZADtaMYBAnF0AJXQBHZOlQwAPABUiABTjoAHvgkATVHBwSAngG0AugD4AFDjDAAXHFcA6ALAcKBwQVB99AEo4AF5nOH12EGAMXWdohBE4OFo5TTh7XlRICQwiDBhlYrz0R1iFbDx0XTgAHzgJZEo3TspIgG4RLJy8+BZ0GFoACwARPBx6tHQyShoGV2Hs-0Dg0PCE6LjETezrT22-IJCwyJPTuD8YKfQJV1dzecP4zOF7v7gKlUShh3vNrFYdAM7qdGLdfjCCCd7B5gI5EfCofDeDBkFB5EgisDCKwJtM5rg4IxBsJGENRMIYLYwOg4ECagBBepIHA+TRQYASADmlJEjOZrI0RIAQly4FReTB+UKRcJzOhaORgizxFIZHI4OzXJEIkkUs02aV0OznNS1RqtaxJNJZPIpa4wABGHxUCAQch8CTGhKm1IWjBSm10pbKNQaGCudlw6OqdSaVxSyJAA)